# How to solve 3D heat equation with Neumann B.C

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve the 3D heat equation on a cuboid to know if all the perimetric surfaces of a Cuboid achieve the desired temperature of a 873K on deadline time of 2 hours. i have convection on all the surfaces (Neumman B.C), except on the bottom on which i have conduction by a known heat flux (Neumman B.C). I tried the next code:

```
k = 25.5;(*W/(m K)*)
Rho = 7800;(*(kg/m3)*)
c = 500;(*J/(kg K)*)
sig = 5.67*10^-8;(*W/(m^2 K^4)*)
h = 6.98;(*W/(m^2K)*)
Q = 12000(*KW*);
Reg = ImplicitRegion[-0.2 <= x <= 0.2 && -0.7 <= y <= 0.7 && 0 <= z <= 0.3, {x, y, z}];
op = Rho c Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][u][t, x, y, z] - 
k Laplacian[u[t, x, y, z] , {x, y, z}];
BC2 = NeumannValue[-((h*100)/k ) - (0.7 sig (100)^4)/
k , (z == 0.3) || (x == -0.2) || (x == 0.2) || (y == -0.7) || (y == 0.7)]
+NeumannValue[Q/k, z == 0 ]
uifHeat = NDSolveValue[{op == BC2, u[0, x, y, z] == 298}, 
u, {t, 0, 360}, {x, y, z} ∈ Reg];
Labeled[Plot3D[uifHeat[#, x, y, 0.3], {x, -0.2, 0.2}, {y, -0.7, 0.7}],
"t=" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[0, 360, 120]
```

i get the next error:

```
No places were found on the boundary where Coordinate  was True, so \
NDSolve`FEM`BoundaryCondition[{Neumann \
,{1,1},{CompiledFunction[{10,10.2,5568},{_Real,_Real,_Real},{{3,0,0},{\
3,0,1},{3,0,2},{3,2,0}},{{{{-27.5282}},{3,2,0}}},{0,0,3,0,1},{{1}},\
Function[{x,y,z},{{-27.5282}},Listable],Evaluate]}},Coordinate \
,CompiledFunction[{10,10.2,5568},{_Real,_Real,_Real},{{3,0,0},{3,0,1},\
{3,0,2},{2,0,0}},{<<1>>},<<1>>,{{19,0,3},<<49>>,<<11>>},Function[{x,y,\
z},Block[{Compile`$16,Compile`$25},Compile`$16=-x;Compile`$25=-y;\
Boole[<<1>>]],Listable],Evaluate],NeumannValue[-27.52819607843137`,z==\
0.3`||x==-0.2`||x==0.2`||y==-0.7`||y==0.7`]] will effectively be \
ignored. >>
Input value {-0.199971,-0.6999,0.3} lies outside the range of data in  the    interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>
```

and this graphics:
[image: grapihc]

what am i doing wrong?

After getting some help i entered a few changes, I'm trying to use Finite Element Method by meshing the region. i changed the bottom Neumann B.C to Dirichlet B.C, but still getting a interpolation error on the boundary lines of the upper surface:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
k = 25.5;(*W/(m K)*)
Rho = 7800;(*(kg/m3)*)
c = 500;(*J/(kg K)*)
sig = 5.67*10^-8;(*W/(m^2 K^4)*)
h = 6.98;(*W/(m^2K)*)
Q = 12000(*KW*);
Reg = ImplicitRegion[-0.2 <= x <= 0.2 && -0.7 <= y <= 0.7 && 0 <= z <= 0.3 {x, y, z}];
M = ToElementMesh[Reg];
M["Wireframe"]
op = Rho c Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][u][t, x, y, z] - 
k Laplacian[u[t, x, y, z] , {x, y, z}];
IC = u[0, x, y, z] == 298;
BC1 = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y, z] == 873, z == 0];
BC2 = NeumannValue[-((h 100)/k) - (0.7 sig 100^4)/k, (z > 0)];
uifHeat = NDSolveValue[{op == BC2, u[0, x, y, z] == 298}, 
u, {t, 0, 360}, {x, y, z} ∈M];
Labeled[Plot3D[uifHeat[#, x, y, 0.3], {x, -0.2, 0.2}, {y, -0.7, 0.7}],
"t=" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[0, 7200, 1800]
```

the error:

```
"Input value {-0.199971,-0.6999,0.3} lies outside the range of data \
in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."
"Further output of "InterpolatingFunction dmval", will be suppressed during this calculation."
```

pics:
[image]

Comment: Firstly, it would seem that `BC1` has not been defined.  I assume this is an initial condition?

Comment: the initial condition is already in 'unifheat' <u[0, x, y, z] == 298> . BC1 was Dirichlet B.C which i changed to Neumann BC. @drN

Answer (score 9):

The following produces what appears to be the results.  Note that the undefined `BC1` had to be removed, whether or not the initial condition was specified in some other way.

```
BC2 = NeumannValue[-((h*100)/k ) - (0.7 sig (100)^4)/k , z > 0] + 
    NeumannValue[Q/k, z == 0 ]
uifHeat = NDSolveValue[{op == BC2, u[0, x, y, z] == 298}, 
    u, {t, 0, 360}, {x, y, z} ∈ Reg]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @bbgodfrey. about the neumann B.C:         NeumannValue[((h*100)/k ) - (0.7 sig (100)^4)/k , z > 0]     isn't it apply convection on all the surfaces above z>0, and not only the perimeter surfaces that define the cuboid?

Comment: @M  It applies NeumannValue on all spatial surfaces of the cuboid except `z == 0`.  What other surfaces are you thinking of?

Comment: the question is are the convection apply on all the layers besides the envelope surfaces, like the inside layers of z: 0<z<3, ant not only on z=0 and etc.

Comment: i am still getting the extrapolation error on the boundary lines:                           "Input value {-0.199971,-0.6999,0.3} lies outside the range of data \
in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."                                     why the interpolation fails on the boundary lines?

Comment: @MaximKozminov  The NeumannValue boundary conditions are applied only at the real boundaries, not the interior.  You can safely ignore the `Extrapolation message.